# iOS9 WKWebview didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge called with host null

Tags: objective-c, ssl, ios9, wkwebview

I am using `WKWebview` (iOS 9) to load https://self-signed.badssl.com/

While as a delegate `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` is getting called, I'm receiving incomplete `protectionSpace` details e.g. host is null & `authenticationMethod` is `NSURLAuthenticationMethodDefault` (it should be `NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust`)

```
po challenge.protectionSpace
<NSURLProtectionSpace: 0x7ff30c40fb90>: Host:(null), Server:http, Auth-Scheme:NSURLAuthenticationMethodDefault, Realm:(null), Port:0, Proxy:NO, Proxy-Type:(null)
```

Surprisingly if I'm writing fresh code as a new project(rather than writing in my mail project), the same code is working perfectly. So as I'm guessing this could be related to some settings.

Note: For both the code instances, `ATS` is set to true.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
  </dict>
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved: It was due to another Third Party Library which was causing this issue.

Comment: You should give some more details in your answer (which library, what happened in detail, logs, whatever)... it could be useful for someone else.

Comment: We were using AirWatch SDK which was causing this issue while authenticating the challenge received.

Comment: We are in the same situation with AirWatch SDK. Could you please explain what you did.